# How to display items of all versions in a custom list?

Tags: custom-list, view, versioning

Is there anyway to achieve that? I want a view showing all versions of items in given list.

say:

```
ID Version Content
 1       1     aaa
 1       2     bbb
 1       3     ccc
 2       1     ddd
 3       1     eee
```

Answer (score 0):

In the 2013 version click on the Library tab on the Ribbon, Library settings,  click on the view to edit, expand Group By, Group by version.

Comment: not my requirement. i've tested it. please notice that my example there, all 3 versions of item with ID=1 are shown. that is, i want to show all history in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a native way to list the previous versions on the same view. You can try using [JSLink](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/01/using-jslink-to-change-ui-of-sharepoint_20.html) to change the way the list view is rendered.

When drawing the new view use the solution from [This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423657/sharepoint-2013-get-splistitem-versions-via-rest) to query the previous versions and display them.

I do not see this behaving with acceptable performance for more then a few items though...

Comment: oh yes... actually you can consider i've tested all obvious api could be found in MSDN. i used SOAP to query the history of fields of particular items in a list, and that consumes lots of bandwidth. it seems i have good reason to convince my boss.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to cache the information necessary for the rendering somewhere else to speed things up, maybe a web service or auxiliary list... Still, I think it's a requirement you should try to change. Do they REALLY need to see all versions of ALL items every time they open the page?

Comment: no. by displaying all versions, it's more convenient to use query to filter out the specific version of given item and that's the original motivation. the query is done on server side so that the load of bandwidth could be decreased.